# Read certain lines of data from text files in SAS

Tags: text, sas, data-manipulation

I have a text file `c:\test.txt` with lot of information and I need only a few details from the file. Here is how my data looks

```
an army of ants
bchskkkk/kk/kl
id: intyst@abc.com
subject: this is an email
   to xyz
kkdkdlkadkadk;kd;
jjdjsjdlasjdaljdljd
<st> This is my actual content
      klfjaakjalkjflajflajefljalkfj
      daklkajflkjalfkjaljflkajfkl
 kkdlkal;dka;ldk <st>
```

In the above the rows starting with id, subject, and a few rows with start and end as  are what I need in my dataset

This is what I have tried

```
 filename data 'c:\test.txt';

 data want;
 infile data lrecl=1000 missover;
 input #3 $ id 3-25 #4 $ sub1 10-25  #8 $ cmc 4-55
 run;
```

The above doesn't solve my purpose. I have some 10k lines in each file with the above format and the text between  and  can be more than 10 rows.

Is there any better way of solving this?

Thank you

Comment: For the provided data file, what is the desired data set ? I.e., what are the column names ? Do you what the data up to the first <st>, or the data between the oddly paired tags <st> ... <st> (would have expected <st>...</st>

Comment: I would like to have the data for the columns that Inm mentioned in the input statement. Id will be the email id next to ‘Id’, sub is the subject line next to ‘subject’ and CMC should be the text between paired tags <st>.. <st>

Comment: Do the matching `<st>` tags always appear at beginning/ending of lines? As in your example?  or could they appear in the middle of lines?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot grab the data using a single input statement.

You will need to do 'landmark' detection in order to discover and extract the data portions you want, all the while retaining the parts you find as you scan the file.

Presuming `id:` is always a new data set row indicator and  always present as the final part for a row, the following could work (not tested):

```
data messages;
  length id $50;
  length subject $100;
  length message $1000;

  retain id subject message;

  infile data lrecl=1000 _infile_=line;

  input;

  if line =: "id" then do;
    id_line_number = _n_;
    id = substr(line,length("id:")+1);
    subject = "";
    content = "";
  end;

  if subject = "" and line =: "subject:" then do;
    subject = substr(line,length("subject:")+1);
  end;

  if message = "" then do;
    if line =: "<st>" then do;
      * initial line in <st> block;
      message = line;
    end;
  end;
  else do;
    * accumulate lines within <st> block;
    message = trim(message) || ' ' line;
  end;

  * termination of <st> block, triggers a complete record and output to data set;
  if length(message)>4 and substr(message,length(message)-3) = "<st>" then do;
    message = substr(message,5,length(message)-8);
    output;
    message = "";
  end;
run;
```

Some additional coding would be needed if the subject can be wrapped and is continued in subsequent adjacent lines as indented content